# Where I can see details about protection in a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, protected-questions

I have protected this question below:

[Angular.js Backbone.js or which has better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458436/angular-js-backbone-js-or-which-has-better-performance)

But I am unable to see the protection details anywhere. Why?

[image]

Comment: Why are we protecting a closed question?

Comment: @Paulie_D But i can see the Protect button for those questions.

Comment: So...that's not what you asked. Just becuase you can see an option doesn't mean you have to use it.

Comment: @Paulie_D But it's related with that.

Comment: [The timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11458436/timeline) says it was you that protected it.  Hopefully you know why you did that.  And hopefully you stop doing that.

Comment: Then you need to make your question clearer...but my question still remains. Why protect this question?

Comment: @Paulie_D I am just try to test and know the functionality.

Comment: Oh...I wouldn't recommend clicking things just because you can to see what happens.

Comment: Maybe a mod can try to test and know the functionality of account suspension....

Comment: Do you often randomly try stuff in production at work? Because.... You shouldn't do it here either

Comment: I've long believed that privileges should not be based on rep alone. Privileges should be based on rep and other indicators. For example, maybe protecting/unprotecting questions should only be allowed to users who have 10k _and_ the Marshal badge.

Answer (score 7):

Protecting a question means that you need at least 10 reputation (earned on Stack Overflow) to answer the question.
Answering a question is not possible with a closed question. Therefore, its protected/unprotected status **does not matter anymore**. (Unless it's reopened in the future, but then it will show the 'protected' banner again.)

As Hans Passant mentioned in the comments, the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11458436/timeline) is the place where you can still see who protected it (a 15k user or ['automatically' by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226619/295232)).

Comment: Does protected status prevent it from being deleted?

Comment: @S.L.Barth no..